# How can I make two Ruby symbols point to the same object?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am assigning a temp password to my users.

Now I have this as code and it works:

```
temp_password = random_pronouncable_password
@user = User.create!(params[:user].merge(:password => temp_password, :password_confirmation => temp_password))
```

but I want a way to be able to do this

```
@user = User.create!(params[:user].merge(:password, :password_confirmation => temp_password))
```

Anyone know how to do something like this?

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have two, then just repeat them and maybe format your code to make the repeat obvious:

```
@user = User.create!(params[:user].merge(
    :password              => temp_password,
    :password_confirmation => temp_password
))
```

Anything else will just be a bunch of extra noise that serves no useful purpose. Anyone that looks at the above will immediately know what's going on with barely a thought and that's an indicator of good clean code.

You could probably come up with something clever using the [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000716) constructor or possibly a [Hash with a default value](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000718) but that would be a waste of cleverness. Cleverness is in limited supply so you should save it for special occasions when it is really needed.

Answer (score 1):

No.

First of all, `params[:user]` is a ruby hash.  A hash associates objects with other objects.  Common it associates a symbol as the key, and some other object as the value.  So you dont make a symbol point to anything.

Second, calling this invoked `Hash#merge` which expects another Hash.  All keys and values on the has you pass to merge are merged with the receiver.  SO you have to pass a real and valid hash to it.

Third, the `validates_confirmation_of` call that requires you to do this in rails is designed to prevent this use.  It makes it very hard to set a user to an incorrect password by forcing you to set it twice.  Forcing this into a single assignment goes against the spirit of the feature and deserves to be explicitly assigned to both keys.

So your first snippet is correct, and is what should be used in this case.